# Puppeteer Error: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am trying to build a small API that uses Puppeteer to navigate to a website, logs in, and collects some data for me. However, when testing my initial try, I keep getting an error that says `Puppeteer Error: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`

One potential factor could be that the page is a SPA, and so there is no actual navigation change after logging in. I have tried with and without `waitForNavigation`.

I have logged out the html of the page after log in and I can see that it is successfully rendering the element I'm trying to interact with, but the application shuts down with this error every time.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function takeScreenshot(tournamentId) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  try {
    await page.goto('my-url');
    await page.type('#email', 'my-email');
    await page.type('#password', 'my-password');

    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation(),
      page.click('button[type="submit"]')
    ]);

    const selector = `a[href*="/tournaments/${tournamentId}"]`;
    const tournamentLink = await page.$(selector);

    if (tournamentLink) {
      await tournamentLink.click();
      
      const playersLinkSelector = `a[href="/tournaments/${tournamentId}/players"]`;
      const playersLink = await page.$(playersLinkSelector);
      
      if (playersLink) {
        await playersLink.click();
        
        const screenshotPath = '../screenshots/players_page.png';
        await page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath });
        
        console.log(`Screenshot saved at: ${screenshotPath}`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Puppeteer Error:', error);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}

module.exports = {
  takeScreenshot,
};
```

Comment: What is `'my-url'`? SPA route changes are counted as navigations by Puppeteer. You're waiting for one, but if `await playersLink.click();` triggers a nav then that must be `waitForNavigation()`ed as well. More reliable is often to scrape the href out of the link and use `page.goto(urlTakenFromLink)` rather than actually clicking it. It's easy to get fixated on using the site the same way a human would, but that's only necessary in testing scenarios.